# Why Jest 24.8 Coverage produce coverage === 0

Tags: javascript, jestjs, code-coverage, istanbul, test-coverage

```
 PASS  ../parser/test/flatten-user-flow-shortcuts.spec.ts
 PASS  ../parser/test/flow-spliterators.spec.ts
 PASS  ../parser/test/circles1.spec.js
 PASS  ../parser/test/circles.spec.ts
 PASS  ../parser/test/replace-basic-flows.spec.ts
 PASS  ../parser/test/multiple-flows-in-first-layer.spec.ts
 PASS  ../parser/test/multiple-layers.spec.ts
 PASS  ../parser/test/extends-basic-flows.spec.ts

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  modulePaths: resolveModulesPathsArray,
  testRegex: [`./*.spec.js$`, `./*.spec.ts$`],
  roots: [mainTestsFolderPath, srcPath],
  transform: { '^.+\\.js$': jestTransformerFilePath, '^.+\\.ts$': jestTransformerFilePath },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [`coverage`, 'node_modules'],
  setupFiles: [testPolyfillsFilePath],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [`${srcPath}/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,json}`],
}
```

srcPath is the absolute path to my src folder.

#### My Question

I'm sure I forgot to configure something. I even checked this in a new create-react-app when running `"test": "react-scripts test --coverage",` and I see the same results.

What is the cause of it?